# How to properly transform UIView's scale on UIScrollView movement

Tags: swift, uiview, uiscrollview

To have a similar effect to Snapchat's HUD movement, I have created a movement of the HUD elements based on `UIScollView's` `contentOffset`. **Edit: [Link to the Github project](https://github.com/davidseek/SnapchatCamera)**.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    let factor = scrollView.contentOffset.y / self.view.frame.height

    self.transformElements(self.playButton,
                           0.45 + 0.55 * factor, // 0.45 = desired scale + 0.55 = 1.0 == original scale
                           Roots.screenSize.height - 280, // 280 == original Y
                           Roots.screenSize.height - 84, // 84 == minimum desired Y
                           factor)
}

func transformElements(_ element: UIView?,
                       _ scale: CGFloat,
                       _ originY: CGFloat,
                       _ desiredY: CGFloat,
                       _ factor: CGFloat) {
    if let e = element {
        e.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale) // this line lagging

        let resultY = desiredY + (originY - desiredY) * factor
        var frame = e.frame
        frame.origin.y = resultY
        e.frame = frame
    }
}
```

With this code implemented the scroll as well as the transition appeared to be "laggy"/not smooth. (Physical iPhone 6S+ and 7+).

Deleting the following line: `e.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)` erased the issue. The scroll as well as the `Y-movement` of the `UIView` object is smooth again.

What's the best approach to transform the scale of an object?

[image]

There are no Layout Constraints.

```
func setupPlayButton() {
        let rect = CGRect(x: Roots.screenSize.width / 2 - 60,
                          y: Roots.screenSize.height - 280,
                          width: 120,
                          height: 120)
        self.playButton = UIButton(frame: rect)
        self.playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "playBtn")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
        self.playButton.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        self.view.addSubview(playButton)
}
```

Comment: Does your button have a transparent background?  If it does, can you turn it off and try again?  You can also try `button.layer.shouldRasterize = true` while its animating.

Comment: the button has no color. just a UIImage (pdf with transparent elements)

Comment: from your gif, try setting the background black.

Comment: `layer.shouldRasterize = true` = still laggy . lemme check BG. sec

Comment: `backgroundColor = .black` = still laggy

Comment: Can you try a bitmap asset, rather than a PDF?  I have certainly done this sort of parallax scrolling exactly like this, and its typically very smooth.  How have you embedded your PDF, as 'Single Vector'?

Comment: yes as single vector. i will try with a regular bmp/png. sec

Comment: tried it with PNG @1-3 instead of single vector PDF. same. i'll upload the project to my git. it's SERIOUSLY short. in case you're interested to check it out

Comment: https://github.com/davidseek/SnapchatCamera

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141993/discussion-between-dmorrow-and-david-seek).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are applying both: `transform` and `frame`. It will be smoother, if you apply only `transform`. Update your `transformElements` function as below:

```
    func transformElements(_ element: UIView?,
                       _ scale: CGFloat,
                       _ originY: CGFloat,
                       _ desiredY: CGFloat,
                       _ factor: CGFloat) {
    if let e = element {
        e.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale).translatedBy(x: 0, y: desiredY * (1 - factor))

    }
}
```

Comment: well. the formula doesn't work anymore with this approach. but the transition is smooth af. just need to adjust the formula. think this will be my way to go. thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can make these kinds of animation smoother by creating an animation then setting the speed of the layer to 0 and then changing the timeOffset of the layer.

first add the animation in the `setupPlayButton` method

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: "transform.scale")
animation.fromValue = 1.0
animation.toValue = 0.45
animation.duration = 1.0
//Set the speed of the layer to 0 so it doesn't animate until we tell it to
self.playButton.layer.speed = 0.0;
self.playButton.layer.add(animation, forKey: "transform");
```

next in the `scrollViewDidScroll` change the timeOffset of the layer and move the center of the button.

```
if let btn =  self.playButton{
    var factor:CGFloat = 1.0
    if isVertically {
        factor = scrollView.contentOffset.y / self.view.frame.height
    } else {
        factor = scrollView.contentOffset.x / Roots.screenSize.width
        var transformedFractionalPage: CGFloat = 0

        if factor > 1 {
           transformedFractionalPage = 2 - factor
        } else {
            transformedFractionalPage = factor
        }
        factor = transformedFractionalPage;
    }
    //This will change the size
    let timeOffset = CFTimeInterval(1-factor)
    btn.layer.timeOffset = timeOffset

    //now change the positions.  only use center - not frame - so you don't mess up the animation.  These numbers aren't right I don't know why
    let desiredY = Roots.screenSize.height - (280-60);
    let originY = Roots.screenSize.height - (84-60);
    let resultY = desiredY + (originY - desiredY) * (1-factor)
    btn.center = CGPoint.init(x: btn.center.x, y: resultY);
}
```

I couldn't quite get the position of the button correct - so something is wrong with my math there, but I trust you can fix it.

If you want  more info about this technique see here: http://ronnqvi.st/controlling-animation-timing/

Comment: your approach is working as well. but the other answer does it way easier and is coming closer to my approach. but i will wait and see what other options are available. you'll receive the well deserved upvote either way once the bounty period is over! thank you very much for your effort